# Stripe not reload/redirect page after payment

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have smarty template form where is shown Stripe payment button.

```
<div>
    <!-- Stripe -->
        <form action="/payment.php?custom=1&sum={$sum*100}" method="POST">
            <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                data-key="pk_live_xxxxxxxxx"
                data-amount="{$sum*100}"
                data-description="payment"
                data-locale="auto"
                data-zip-code="true">
            </script>
                                                                          
        </form>
        <div style="font-size: 10px; padding: 0 0 0 22px">powered by <a href="https://stripe.com/" target=_blank" rel="nofolow">stripe</a></div>
</div>
```

Then my php file `payment.php`

```
if($_REQUEST['stripeToken']) {
    
    require_once('stripe_4/init.php');
    
    try {
      // Use Stripe's library to make requests...
      
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_live_xxxxxxxxxx");

        $token = $_REQUEST['stripeToken'];

        if ($_GET['custom'] == 1) {
            $price = $_GET['sum'];
            $calback_url = 'ppdpam';
            $description = "Custom payment";
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION['stripe_error_message'] = "Wrong parameters!";
            header("Location: https://".SITE."/data.php?er=100$parameter");
            exit;
        }
        
        // Charge the user's card:
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
          "amount" => $price,
          "currency" => "usd",
          "description" => $description,
          "source" => $token,
        ));
        
    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
      // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
      $body = $e->getJsonBody();
      $err  = $body['error'];
    
      print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
      print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
      print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");
      // param is '' in this case
      print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
      print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
      
      $_SESSION['stripe_error_message'] = $e->getMessage();
      header("Location: /data.php?er=1$parameter");
      exit;
    
    header("Location: https://".SITE."/data.php?".$calback_url);
    exit;
}
```

When I click on Stripe button I get the popup where I put data of my card. Then I click Pay i've got green tick on the popup (assuming that the payment is okay) and then nothing happens.

There is nothing in the Stripe, like the payment isn't even get there and there is no charge on my card.

It should redirect me to the URL along with the `$calback_url` parameter. All I got is gray Stripe button and need to manually refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you're using Legacy Checkout which Stripe deprecated well over 3 years ago and actively discourages using. It's not really maintained and no new integration should rely on it (though it does still work since they wouldn't break existing users).

You should be using one of Stripe's numerous newer features from [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) to [Payment Links](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links), the [Pricing Table](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table) or their "pay what you want" [feature](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links).

It is crucial to switch off as Legacy Checkout doesn't support many of the newer features such as 3D Secure, mandates for India payments, saving card details for future payments and many more.

Ultimately though, the first part of your code opens Legacy Checkout which is a modal/popup to collect card details. It doesn't accept a payment at all, it just collects card details and creates a card Token `tok_123`. Then your form on the page gets submitted with the Token id in `$_POST['stripeToken']`. Your code looks at `$_REQUEST['stripeToken']` but then does nothing with it and later you reference `'source' => $token` without having ever defined that variable. Unfortunately that means you have multiple PHP errors and your script must be crashing as you also don't handle any of Stripe's API [errors](https://stripe.com/docs/error-handling). If you fix that, the redirect should work, but really you should never be using that code and rely on one of the options I mention above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have actually used $token. Updated my question with the full code. I know that is legacy and we're in the process of updating but while this is done we need a bit tweak on this one. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately the first step is for you to carefully handle errors returned by Stripe, adding clear logs to grasp which exact part of your code is failing and go from there.